# ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http): missing required field "paths"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, fusionauth, helm3

I have the following code in my values.yaml file:

```
ingress:
  kind: Ingress
  hostname: auth.localhost
  enabled: true
  metadata: fusionauth-ingress
  hosts:
    - host: auth.local
  spec:
    rules:
      http:
        paths: "/"
      path:
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 8080
            serviceName: fusionauth
            servicePort: 9011
```

When I run: `helm upgrade --install fusionauth-init --values fusionauth/values.yaml fusionauth`

I get the following error: `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http): missing required field "paths" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.HTTPIngressRuleValue`

I am new to Helm but I cannot seem to find where the error in my logic is.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your posted code seems incomplete, or indented funny, or not a kubernetes `Ingress` resource, or maybe some combination of those, but you'll find [the reference guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#ingressrule-v1-networking-k8s-io) invaluable for knowing how the official one is supposed to be shaped. Good luck

Comment: The indentation is off here. However, a helm lint works fine so I know the YAML is valid in my source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the [chart source](https://github.com/FusionAuth/charts/blob/0f86a961777108139fcd600ead7c08a28a1ea058/chart/values.yaml#L172), your values are all invalid. You cannot copy K8s ingress spec directly for FusionAuth, you need to follow the [structure of the chart values.yaml](https://github.com/FusionAuth/charts/blob/master/chart/values.yaml), the chart value meanings are [here](https://github.com/FusionAuth/charts#chart-values). If you were following the instruction [here](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/kubernetes/fusionauth-deployment/#create-an-ingress) previously to create an K8s Ingress resource, you **do not** need to deploy Ingress again using helm.

Comment: Thanks. It was a misunderstanding on my part. I changed it as requested and everything is working. Thanks so much for pointing this out. The documentation for using helm dependencies is unfortunately not very clear..